# is there a way to change the menu text colour when at the top of a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a menu that has a background which is seethrough at the top and when you scroll down the background color of the menu changes to black. In one of my pages the background of the whole website is white so when the user scrolls to the top, the menu background is white which makes it impossible to read the menu text. 
I was wondering if there is a code that can change the color of the text of the menu when the menu bar is at the top of the website the menu text changes black so it is readable. here is a picture when the menu bar is at the top of the website
 and not at the top. I'll add the code that codes for the menu bar.
[image: top of the website]

[image]

HTML & Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Croydon Cycles</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="shop-style.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="parallax.min.js"></script>
</head>




<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>

                <nav>

                    <div class="menu-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="logo">
                            Croydon Cycles
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                                <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>

        </header>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Menu-toggle button

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
            $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
    });
    // add this instruction !
    setTimeout(function() {plusSlides(1) }, 1000)
})

    // Scrolling Effect

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                $('nav').addClass('black');
        }

        else {
                $('nav').removeClass('black');
        }
    })


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}



header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(hero.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.content {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}


.logo {
    line-height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index:2;
}

nav ul {
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

    .logo {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          margin-top: 16px;
    }

    nav ul {
          max-height: 0px;
          background: #000;
    }

    nav.black ul {
          background: #000;
    }

    .showing {
          max-height: 34em;
    }

    nav ul li {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 24px;
          text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-icon {
          display: block;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html lang="en">` tags?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, must have pasted it wrong

Comment: did you check the developer console for any js errors?

Comment: there are no js errors in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the correct colors for `.black` class. 
Before run the snippet click and Expand Snippet, because I added for large resolutions only, you can add in `@media(max-width: 786px)` for small resolutions (mobile devices).

I added `<div style="height:1500px" class="only-for-scroll"></div>` to force scroll.

I commented with `//add this` to you identify the changes that I did.

```css
html, body {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}



header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(hero.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.content {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}
/*add this lines*/
nav.black .logo {
  color: #fff;
}
nav.black ul li a {
 color: #fff;
}
/*END*/


nav .logo {
    line-height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #000; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}


nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index:2;
}

nav ul {
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="parallax.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>

                <nav>

                    <div class="menu-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="logo">
                            Croydon Cycles
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                                <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>

        </header>
        
        <div style="height:1500px" class="only-for-scroll"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    // Menu-toggle button

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
       $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
    });
    // add this instruction !
    //setTimeout(function() {plusSlides(1) }, 1000)
})

    // Scrolling Effect

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    
        if($(window).scrollTop()) {
             $('nav').addClass('black');

        }

        else {
             $('nav').removeClass('black');
        }
    })


</script>
```